# unmet dependencies notification in top panel ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, error-handling

I don't know why I am getting this from some days in the top panel, though it is different every time

[image]

got this on apt update

> Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EF4186FE247510BE
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EF4186FE247510BE
> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

these two methods didn't solve it
[y-ppa-manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/386003/1112104),
[keyserver](https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/1112104)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try removal and adding this PPA back by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I removed Mozilla PPA but that notification is still there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mozilla repo is not longer active.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease
```

The errors says something wrong with permissions.
Try again

```
sudo apt update
```

if this is not working

```
software-properties-gtk
```

and choose download from main server.